# Android upload image

Tags: android, image, upload

Greetings,

I'm trying to upload an image on my Android device.

I have the following code which causes the image picker to come up and examine the SD card (which is what I want).

```
Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
            startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, 1);
```

But what do I do next? Is there some class I can override to handle the image that was clicked on? I've tried googling but can't find anything. I hope someone can point me in the right direction.

---

Tried taking willytate's advice, but now I keep getting the following error:

```
02-08 16:58:01.574: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(16962): FATAL EXCEPTION: WebViewCoreThread
02-08 16:58:01.574: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(16962): java.lang.NullPointerException
02-08 16:58:01.574: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(16962):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:2890)
02-08 16:58:01.574: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(16962):     at prestocab.driver.Main$Uploader.upload(Main.java:172)
02-08 16:58:01.574: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(16962):     at android.webkit.WebViewCore.nativeTouchUp(Native Method)
02-08 16:58:01.574: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(16962):     at android.webkit.WebViewCore.access$3300(WebViewCore.java:66)
02-08 16:58:01.574: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(16962):     at android.webkit.WebViewCore$EventHub$1.handleMessage(WebViewCore.java:1226)
02-08 16:58:01.574: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(16962):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-08 16:58:01.574: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(16962):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:143)
02-08 16:58:01.574: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(16962):     at android.webkit.WebViewCore$WebCoreThread.run(WebViewCore.java:642)
02-08 16:58:01.574: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(16962):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1102)
```

Here is my class:

```
public class Uploader extends Activity{   //uploader
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        }
        public void upload(){
            Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
            startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent,0);

        }
        @Override
        public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
                String selectedImagePath = data.getDataString();
                Toast.makeText(Main.this, selectedImagePath, 2000);
            }
        }
    }
```

Many thanks in advance,

Comment: Hey, I ended up having to get a rentacoder...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eamorr,

You will need to catch the returned image in `onActivityResult()`.  You will have the check the `requestCode` value to make sure it was the intent you wanted that returned.  In your case you put a `1`.  Then handle the image upload...like so:

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        switch(requestCode) {
        case 1:
            imageUri = data.getData();  //get the Uri of the image from the returned data
            //upload imageUri
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT:
Eamorr.

Use this function to get the ImagePath string insted of `data.getDataString()`.  Just pass in `imageUri`.

```
public String getPath(Uri uri) {
    String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
    Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
    startManagingCursor(cursor);
    int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    return cursor.getString(column_index);
}
```

I actually have the same functionality in my app so I've been through all these hurdles ><

Comment: Hey, thanks for that. I think I'm getting somewhere now. I have an "Uploader" subclass. I've just extended it from "Activity" and I'm hoping things will work the way I plan! Cheers from Ireland,

Comment: Hey willytate, just edited my post. If you've any more insight, it would be greatly appreciated.